# How do you determine each average for a subset of columns in a Kusto table without specify each column by name

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a Kusto table with 100's of 'duration' columns.  I want to calculate the average duration for each of these columns.  Since the number of columns is so large and ever-changing I would like to create the query without hardcoding the column names.

Created a Query that prints out a string that represents a hardcoded version of my query

```
SomeTable
| getschema 
| where ColumnName endswith '_duration'
| summarize  Columns = make_list(ColumnName)
// Make the query
| project strcat('SomeTable | summarize avg(', array_strcat(Columns, '), avg('), ') by Day = startofday(Event_ReceivedTime)')
```

My goal is to have a query that does not require a list of every single column in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to do this all at once instead of generating a query string and then executing that query string? If so, check out [evaluate narrow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/narrowplugin). If your dataset isn't too big, that might get the job done. Here's an example.

```
datatable(id:int, timestamp:datetime, x_duration:timespan, y_duration:timespan, z_duration:timespan)
[1, datetime(2019-07-19 17:51), time(01:00:00), time(02:00:00), time(03:00:00),
 2, datetime(2019-07-19 17:52), time(01:10:00), time(02:10:00), time(03:10:00),
 3, datetime(2019-07-19 17:53), time(01:10:10), time(02:10:10), time(03:10:10)]
| evaluate narrow()
| where Column endswith('_duration')
| extend Value = totimespan(Value)
| summarize avg(Value) by Column


Column      avg_Value
x_duration  01:06:43.3333333
y_duration  02:06:43.3333333
z_duration  03:06:43.3333333
```

Comment: That did the trick! My table will have tens of thousands of entries but hopefully, perf won't be too bad.